# Add attribute to activerecord after findAll call in YII framework

Tags: activerecord, yii

I am calling the `findAll` method and i am getting 4 fields.I now want to add one more field named `$owned`.
SO that means after i get the record form the table, the resultant datarecord should contain the owned field.
Also the `$owned` field is dynamic based on whether user is the owner of the group. I tried using `afterFind`. But it is also not working. Surprisingly it is adding attributed `$owned` to the object but not to attributes.
I am using `CJSON::encode($model)` in controller to see the output.The `$owned` field is not showing.
below is the code

```
/**
*
* The followings are the available columns in table 'group':
* @property integer $id
* @property string $name
* @property string $created_at
* @property string $updated_at
*/

class Group extends CActiveRecord
{
//adding owned property for groups.true if user is owner

    public $owned;

protected function afterFind()
{

    parent::afterFind();
    //if user is owner of group its true
    $this->owned = true;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole `Group` model in your question? Have you defined `owned` as an attribute by declaring it in the `rules()` method?

Comment: You could try to call `parent::afterFind()` after the assignation (not sure it'll change anything, but u could give it a try)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out. It is the problem with the CJSON::encode problem. this method only encodes the properties of the model. It doesn't encode any relational or dynamic property. SO i wrote my own function and it works.!

Hope this helps someone in future

Thanks to all
Smith

Answer (score 0):

---

Try Following code:

```
public function init()
    {
        $this->onAfterFind=array($this,'afterFindCustom');
        parent::init();
    }

    public function afterFindCustom()
    {
        $this->owned = true;
        parent::afterFind();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh. I got the error "( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\yii-1.1.12.b600af\framework\collections\CListIterator.php on line 91". the line parent::afterFind() in afterFindCustom causes this error.

Comment: Yes, you have to remove the parent::afterFind() call from afterFindCustom(). The onAfterFind event is triggered by the afterFind function so calling it again means that you are creating an endless loop. No need to return anything or call a parent function there.

Comment: Thanks Blizz...still does not work..In my code    $groups = Tabs::model()->findAll('user_id = :userID',array(':userID'=>$userID));. Now after fetching is there any way i can add any additional property to the $groups object array. Becuse i am not able to add anything. Upon doing print_r, it dumps me an entire object with many properties and all...